# Severe sound clipping in YouTube at maximum volume

Tags: youtube

For the last few months, many of the videos in YouTube have severe clipping unless I lower the volume *in the YouTube player* to about 50%.

It doesn't matter how much I lower the volume of my speakers or headphones; the clipping is there even at the lowest settings. Hence I'm pretty sure the clipping occurs in the YouTube player.

Is this a YouTube bug, or have I mis-configured something?